# Is it possible to remove/hide/remove the "Stock Images" in SharePoint Online webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, web-part, modern-experience, sitepages

I have a requirement  to hide or not show "Stock Images" and "Web Search" etc when selecting an image to a web part. Is it possible to do that using PowerShell or some command?

I would like to use organization assets library and have a dedicated site for it to store all images etc.

But we don't want users to use the out of the box "Stock Images" and "Web Search".

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try below solution, is it working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try using below SharePoint Online PowerShell command to hide web search images:

```
Set-SPOTenant -FilePickerExternalImageSearchEnabled $false
```

Documentation: [Set-SPOTenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/set-spotenant?view=sharepoint-ps)

Follow below articles for setting up organization assets libraries in SharePoint:

1. [Create an Organization Assets Library in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2024/01/30/create-an-organization-assets-library-in-sharepoint-online/)
2. [Register SharePoint Document Library as an Organization Assets Library using PowerShell](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2024/02/03/register-sharepoint-document-library-as-an-organization-assets-library-using-powershell/)

Comment: Thanks Ganesh.
I have provisioned the Org Assets library but stillwaiting forit to show.
In regards to disabling the web search images. Will that also disable both the web search images and the stock images?
About the Onedrive and Sites can this also be removed?

Comment: You may need to wait for some time to see the Org Assets library as well as to disable the web search images. I don't think you will be able to remove OneDrive and Sites option - I will have to check if there is any possibility.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Hopefully it will come through

Comment: Yes, let me know how it goes.